# Do not resize window on drag after super right/left

Tags: gnome, window-manager, gnome-shell, window

In GNOME one can press

- <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>⇨</kbd> (Move window leftmost and resize 50%x100%)
- <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>⇦</kbd> (Move window rightmost and resize 50%x100%)
- <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd> (Maximize)
- <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>⇩</kbd> (Restore)

Right / Left option gives a nice way to quickly do a even split screen which I often use.

Problem is that I frequently want to move one or the other to center of screen,

using <kbd>Super</kbd>+*Mouse pointer* move

without restoring the size of the window. Is there a way to do this? If I want to restore size I use <kbd>Super</kbd><kbd>⇩</kbd> anyway.

I want it to stay at 50% width, 100% height.